# rsync can't complete upload due to connection drops

Tags: linux, rsync

I am trying to upload ~3 million jpegs files, ~90GB, to a remote server.
At first I thought rsync would be great for the job and at first it did saturate my upload link completely.

However my internet connection is somewhat unstable and drops every few hours. It appears the rsyncs startup phase takes substantially longer to complete when there already are some files in the target directory, apparently checking all the files for changes. This process now takes hours before it starts to upload any new files. My connection does not stay up that long, restarting the process.

So I effectively make no progress at all anymore, because the startup takes too long and gets cancelled before it can complete. I need rsync or something like rsync that is aware of connection drops and can reconnect without losing all the progress.

Is there such a tool or option for rsync?

Comment: Make sure to include the options `--partial --progress` so `rsync` can pick up where it left off after failure. `rsync` is the correct tool.

Comment: I assume that the 3 million JPEGs aren't all in the same directory? Could you divide the process per directory to have a manageable size (<100K each)?

Comment: They're all in the same directory. I know that is a lot of files for a single directory, but it works fine in all regards, except the restart issue.

Comment: Then you can rsync `a*`, `b*`, etc... and use any strategy where you rsync only manageable parts of the files.

Comment: That's a great idea. I should've thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of thoughts -

Is rsync checksumming the files? If so, change the behaviour to date/time and filesize and make sure these attributes are being preserved.

Set up OpenVPN between the client and server and rsync across that. Because the IP addresses of the endpoints dont change and because there is no NAT to break the connection, when OpenVPN resumes rsync will continue where it left off.

Comment: open vpn is a cool idea. I'll try that on the next connection drop. However over night my connection was nice to me and right now it is transfering files. Maybe I will get lucky. If not, open vpn it is.

Answer (score 0):

If your files is unchanged from the initial rsync, you can try the rsync option of `--ignore-existing` to ignore the existing files on the receiving remote server and just progress with what is not on it.

Comment: Tried that just now. It does not appear to help. The verbose logging output during startup changes from "file xyz uptodate" to "file xyz exists", but it still goes through all of the files and checks that they exist, which appears to be just as slow as making sure they are uptodate.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize my experience for future googlers:

- Trying to split up files in multiple batches by copying a*, b*, etc is a good idea and helped to complete the upload
- The actual problem was that I had made the mistake of selecting a HDD volume on the cloud server I was uploading to. A HDD cannot handle a directory with 3 million files at all, even tools like cp were not able to further move the data elsewhere from the HDD, just spending forever preparing at 100% disk waits without actually doing any file copying. After using an SSD instead the startup process of rsync is much faster and poses no more problem.